# Prime Decomposition in Two Dimensional Manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

There is *Prime Decomposition* in 3-dimensional manifold, so I want to ask if there exist *Prime Decomposition* in 2-dimensional manifolds.

> I think no, because $\mathbb T^2$#$\mathbb RP^2$=$\mathbb RP^2$#$\Bbb{R}P^2$#$\Bbb{R}P^2$.

Am I correct?